# Leaflet marker draggable not working when function is called from a button

Tags: javascript, draggable, leaflet, marker

I am trying to create a function to be called by `<a href="??">Button</a>` that drops a marker at the center of the mapView and allows it to be draggable until a button with `id="doneMarkerbtn"` has been clicked to disable dragging.

My following code was able to drop a marker at the center of the mapView. However, the marker is not draggable at all. Hope someone can look at my code and help me with this. Thanks.

**Additional Info:** This code is on a .js file which I import both at the `<head>` and `<body>` of my html. Import twice due to some other functions that requires it at different part of the html. Also note that this code is to be used for a Cordova/Phonegap app.

```
/*  Draws marker on center of mapView and allow user to edit by dragging until done  */
function drawMarker() {   
        //Extend the Default marker class
        var PinMarker = L.Icon.Default.extend({
        options: {
            iconUrl:    'img/marker.png', //directory of pin image
            iconSize:   [26,40] //[width,height] of pin image in pixels
            }
        });
        var pinMarker = new PinMarker();
        var marker = L.marker(map.getCenter(), {icon: pinMarker, draggable: true}).addTo(map); //drop marker on center of mapView

    marker.on('dragend', function (e) { //event activates at the end of a drag
             var coords = e.target.getLatLng(); //gets new latlng of marker
             var lat = coords.lat;
             var lng = coords.lng;
             var latlng = lat+","+lng;
             marker.bindPopup(latlng).openPopup().update(); //popup showing dragend latlng
             });

        var stopDrawButton = document.getElementById('doneMarkerbtn'); //set #doneMarkerbtn as stopDrawButton
        stopDrawButton.addEventListener('click', function(){ //when stopDrawButton clicked
            marker.dragging.disable(); //disable dragging on marker
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you link to an example page demonstrating the issue?

Comment: @tmcw: I don't seem to be able to get my page working on jsfiddle(my first time using it). It is suppose to be called via a button. A map would be created before then.

Here's the link... the map doesnt seem to appear but hope you get a rough idea how it will be used: http://jsfiddle.net/shadowhawk/E97qf/8/